# class instance wont save socket inside itself

Tags: socket.io

Whenever a new user connects to socket.io an event handler will create a new class for that user called Events

```js
const eventHandler = socket => {
  new Events(socket);
};
```

and Events constructor will set its socket to the socket its been given upon creation

```js
class Events {
  constructor(socket) {
    this.socket = socket;
    this.socket.on('test', this.test)
  }

  test() {
    console.log(this.socket); // logs undefined
  }
}
```

the issue is why `this.socket` returns undefined? I think I'm missing how something in socket.io works, help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my own answer, It actually has nothing to do with socket.io but rather how `this` works, further reading: [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)